# Are test cases in Jasmine 2.0 run in parallel

Tags: jasmine

Are tests in Jasmine 2.0 run in parallel?  In my experience they aren't but the article , referenced by [Jasmine.js: Race Conditions when using "runs"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154478/jasmine-js-race-conditions-when-using-runs) suggests that Jasmine does run them in parallel so I wondered if I was writing my tests incorrectly.

Here is a set of tests that I would expect to execute in 1 second instead of 4 seconds.

```
describe("first suite", function() {
  it("first test", function(done) {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    setTimeout(done, 1000);
  });

  it("second test", function(done) {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    setTimeout(done, 1000);
  });
});

describe("second suite", function() {
  it("first test", function(done) {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    setTimeout(done, 1000);
  });

  it("second test", function(done) {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    setTimeout(done, 1000);
  });
});
```

Am I missing something?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dspigarelliMNDNT/2bo511uo/)

Comment: You might want to read [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734025/is-javascript-guaranteed-to-be-single-threaded). I just ran the jsFiddle in Chrome, and it "finished in 4.012s". It may depend on which browser and how JS is implemented.

Comment: There's no reason Jasmine couldn't run async tests in parallel and remain single threaded.  Here's a [fsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dspigarelliMNDNT/vr5Larxx/) of what that might look like in theory.

Comment: jest runs your tests in parallel and actually uses jasmine2 as the runner.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Jasmine does not actually run your specs in parallel in any way. It is however possible to have specs whose asynchronous portion takes long enough that the built-in time limit elapses which will cause jasmine to start running the next spec, even though there may still be code running from earlier specs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you provide link to official jasmine documentation(I could not find one) ? I am interested to understand more, like what is the built-in time limit, how to change it etc. ?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to run your test in parallel and you are using karma as a test launcher, you can use [karma-parallel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-parallel) to split up your tests across multiple browser instances. It runs specs in different browser instances and is very simple and easy to install:

```
npm i karma-parallel
```

and then add the 'parallel' to the frameworks list in karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['parallel', 'jasmine']
  });
};
```

[karma-parallel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-parallel)

Disclosure: I am the author

Comment: Can I use karma-parallel without any browser? need to run jasmine tests (api calls testing)

Comment: I also want to know what @petriichuk asked

Comment: Too late, my devs used Jasmine.   Ugh.