# How to run Jasmine tests in serial

Tags: jasmine

I use jasmine to test my server side code and i need to run tests in serial, not in parallel.

My tests need to make CRUD operation in database. If test are executed in parallel i can't ensure that the database is in a good context for my test

Answer (score 1):

Unless you explicitly choose to create asynchronous tests in Jasmine, everything in Jasmine happens sequentially, in the sense that one test runs only after its preceding test has finished. And if you do write asynchronous tests, then parts of your *single* test may run in parallel, *but you still have the constraint that one test runs only after its preceding test has finished.*

However, there are a couple caveats to be aware of:

- In an async test if your code exceeds Jasmine's timeout period, you might still have code running when Jasmine decides to give up on that test and proceed to the next. (Thanks to @Gregg for this tip; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26918392).)
- "JavaScript is usually considered to have a single thread of execution... however, in reality this isn't quite true, in sneaky nasty ways." I am quoting @bobince from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2734311/115690).