# Running Jasmine Integration Tests in Parallel via Selenium Grid

Tags: node.js, testing, browser, jasmine, automated-tests

I've playing around with jasmine and selenium webdriver for browser automation via node.js. What do I need to configure in order to run tests in parallel? I understand that on a java stack TestNG is often used to run parallel tests, what would be the best tool or configuration to run parallel selenium tests using jasmine and node.js?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are test cases in Jasmine 2.0 run in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652895/are-test-cases-in-jasmine-2-0-run-in-parallel)